# Create a session array from Mysql query

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm not very good yet with sessions or arrays.

Here is what I have so far but I am getting an error

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource.

Here is my code:

```
$checkgroupadmin = $this->db->query("SELECT group_id FROM groupadmin 
  WHERE contact_id = $contactid");
while ($adminrow = mysql_fetch_array($checkgroupadmin, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $_SESSION[group_admin] = array('group'=>$adminrow['group_id']);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: are you using a php framework like codeigniter?  If so you should be using the result generation functions.

Comment: Add var_dump($checkgroupadmin) after the query and show the result

Comment: The query has failed. Always check the result `if (!$checkgroupadmin) echo mysql_error();`

Comment: Are you using any framework ? Why `$this->db->query` to query and `mysql_fetch_array` to fetch ?

Answer (score 1):

> > Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource.

You are getting your error because `$checkgroupadmin` is not an actual query resource that mysql_fetch_array() requires.

```
$checkgroupadmin = $this->db->query("SELECT group_id FROM groupadmin WHERE contact_id = $contactid");`
```

In other words the above object oriented call is not returning a mysql resource query.

Why are you mixing object oriented style with procedural style anyways. Secondly the above code `$this>db->query` should be happening inside a Class' method

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array()` returns an associative array of the current results, but in your code you would just be overwriting the same value in the `$_SESSION` for each result. You likely need to create your own array of resulting IDs and then assign that to a `$_SESSION` variable.

```
// query database
$checkgroupadmin = $this->db->query("SELECT group_id FROM groupadmin WHERE contact_id = $contactid");
// array to hold each group_id
$result_array = array();
// varify that $checkgroupadmin returned results 
if ($checkgroupadmin){
    // get results into associative array
    while ($adminrow = mysql_fetch_array($checkgroupadmin, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        // put the group id into your results array
        $result_array[] = $adminrow['group_id'];
    }
}
// set results array to the 'group_admin' key in $_SESSION
$_SESSION['group_admin'] = $result_array;
```

Please note that the [mysql_* extensions have been deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) and you should be using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.